# Primefaces lightBox closes at click on commandLink

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

It's just a simple Primefaces lightBox I want to use commandLinks in. Unfortunately it simply closes, when I click a commandLink. Is there a way to keep the lightBox open?

Here an example of what my code looks like:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <p:lightBox>
        <h:outputLink value="#">
            <h:outputText value="open lightbox" />
        </h:outputLink>

        <f:facet name="inline">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink>
                        commandLink
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </f:facet>
    </p:lightBox>

</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: you mean, is there any way to keep the lightbox open, even if you click on the `<h:commandLink/>`?

Comment: Exactly. I use it to call a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ajax (asynchronous) request instead of a synchronous request:

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:ajax ... />
</h:commandLink>
```

or as you're using PrimeFaces already, just use `<p:commandLink>` instead (it uses by default already ajax):

```
<p:commandLink ... />
```

With ajax, by default no fresh page replacement with the response is performed (which basically "resets" anything to defaults). You can in case of `<f:ajax>` tell by `render` attribute which parts of the component tree should be updated in the client side and in `<p:commandLink>` by the `update` attribute. E.g. if you want to render/update the parent form only, use `@form`. E.g.

```
<p:commandLink ... update="@form" />
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you again!
I enlarged the form a bit and do it just like you proposed:
`<p:commandLink update="@form"><f:ajax />Dingdong</p:commandLink>`.
And it works.
But in general I'm really having issues with ajax and the Ids for the elements that should update.

Comment: You're welcome. The `<f:ajax>` is by the way unnecessary in `<p:commandLink>` as it uses by default already ajax. See also the answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't get that. Thanks for making it clear once again!

Comment: Some knowledge for posterity:
You can close the lightBox with click on a commandLink/-Button by adding `onclick="light.hide();"` to its attributes.

Comment: Yes, where `light` is its `widgetVar`. Note that you'd rather choose another approach when the form needs to be validated and thus might display validation errors and thus the lightbox should stay open so that the enduser can fix it.

Comment: Ouch! Indeed... that might become a problem. :/

Comment: With a simple fix.. `oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) light.hide()"` ;)

Comment: with `onclick` it works for me but not with `oncomplete`. Is there something going wrong with my ajax request?

Comment: According to my Primefaces User's Guide 3.4 (the PF version I am using) `oncomplete` is also available for `<p:commandLink>`

Comment: now I tried it with `<p:commandLink>` anyway but it didn't work either. Would there be an advantage if `oncomplete` did work?

Comment: From the 3 previous comments, I don't understand the first two ones as I didn't tell otherwise. As to the last comment, well, then there's apparently more into the code which caused it to fail.

Comment: Argh, Freud and things... What I wanted to say was, that according to the [PF User's Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf) and the [VDL Docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/) `oncomplete` is actually also available for **`<p:commandButton>`** in Primefaces' latest version.

Comment: I wanted to let it rest, but then I realised, that using `onclick` provokes the buttons action to be called unwantedly on page reload. I think its best to create a new question for this: [Primefaces commandButton with “onclick” calls action method on page refresh / “oncomplete” has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157424/primefaces-commandbutton-with-onclick-calls-action-method-on-page-refresh-o)