# Primefaces commandButton calls action method on page refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

**Completely edited:**
Maybe I was mixing problems and misinterpreted. After simplifying my code the question simplifies to: How can I prevent the `<p:commandButton>` from executing it's action method on page refresh (like when you hit F5 inside browser window)?

JSF Code:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{bugBean.number}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{bugBean.isComplete()}" />
            <p:commandButton id="entryCommand" value="add"
                action="#{bugBean.increase()}" update="@form" oncomplete="#{bugBean.complete()}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

backing bean code:

```
  package huhu.main.managebean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BugBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private int number;
   private boolean isComplete = false;

   public void increase(){
      number++;
   }

   public void complete(){
      isComplete = true;
   }

   public int getNumber() {
      return number;
   }

   public void setNumber(int number) {
      this.number = number;
   }

   public boolean isComplete() {
      return isComplete;
   }

   public void setComplete(boolean isComplete) {
      this.isComplete = isComplete;
   }
}
```

**Update:**
Even if I remove the `oncomplete` stuff like this an click the `<p:commandButton>` just once, the counter goes up on every page refresh.

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{bugBean.number}" />
        <p:commandButton id="entryCommand" value="add"
            action="#{bugBean.increase()}" update="@form"/>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: With "page refresh", do you mean as in pressing F5/Ctrl+R in webbrowser?

Comment: @BalusC Yeah, that's what I meant!

Comment: Post the rest of your page here, to give some context.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. A commandButton doesn't execute when a page is refreshed, it executes when the button is pressed. Can you clarify?

Comment: That's why theres a problem. The method IS called on refresh. Again and again.

Comment: No-repro on Chrome 22 / FF 16 / IE 9. Which browser exactly are you using? Are you refreshing the initial GET request or the ajax POST request?

Comment: I am using Chrome 22. I just click the button once, the I refresh the page with F5.

Comment: same with FF 16, but that one warns me that any action, that was performed, could be performed again. yeaaaaaah, did chrome warn me too? yes it did. so i suppose that is the answer...

Comment: but isn't there a way to prevent that double form submission on refresh without touching the opportunity to click the button further times on purpose?

Comment: Sounds like that the request wasn't performed by ajax (asynchronously), but just regularly (synchronously). That can happen if you have `ajax="false"` in your real command button code (which isn't present in the code posted so far). Didn't you oversimplify the code in the question too much without testing?

Comment: Actually this one time I really took your advice to heart, to create a new xhtml-file and a new backing bean to be able to show the complete code. And that is the case here. Only modification is the `<h:form>` (see Update) which I cleared from all `oncomplete`-stuff after dropping this issue. What you see is really my full code. And you are right the request seems to be performed regularly as my browser's (Chrome 22) refresh-button turns for a snippet of second into an stop-button which indicates something is loaded. I compared it with other ajax requests - don't show that behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct was lacking Ajax-support due to a missing head definition as it seems. In this case I just added `<h:head/>` right above the `<h:body>`-tag and everything worked fine.

Thanks to all contributors!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the action method `increase()` is not called on each page refresh, but it's called the `complete()` method instead, and this is probably making you think that the action method has been called.

The `oncomplete` attribute inside the `p:commandButton` indicates a **client side** action, and so a JS method, and not a server action: the EL executes `#{bugBean.complete()}` when parses it on each page refresh.

Comment: So the `oncomplete` method is executed on every page refresh whether the button was ever clicked or not? What about the `action` method? Even if I remove `oncomplete`the `action` method is executed on page refresh even if I never ever click the button.

Comment: Yes, in your case the oncomplete method is executed whether the button was clicked or not, because it's an EL expression. No, the action method is not executed on each page refresh. Please check again

Comment: Lester, the `oncomplete` is supposed to execute some JS code when the action method completes. It isn't supposed to execute a JSF backing bean method at all. Any EL expression in `onXXX` attribute is evaluated *immediately* as the page renders, simply because it needs to be converted to JS code. But this is further not related to your strange refresh problem.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your answer, I understand. That's indeed good to know. I am really wondering about that refresh problem: So that is definitely a strange one, considering my code. Can anyone reproduce it with my code or has any other approach of explanation?