# Lightbox iframe close

Tags: javascript, jsf, iframe, primefaces

I have a button inside Lightbox iframe. How to close that iframe by clicking that button?

My code looks like this:

```
<p:lightBox id="posetastavkeListaLightBox" 
            widgetVar="posetastavkeListaLightBoxWidget" 
            iframe="true" width="900px" height="700px">          
</p:lightBox>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close a lightBox primefaces from iframe Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874254/close-a-lightbox-primefaces-from-iframe-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639847/1085891) to [Close a lightBox primefaces from iframe Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874254/close-a-lightbox-primefaces-from-iframe-button)

```
<p:lightBox id="light" iframe="true" width="80%" height="80%" widgetVar="dlg">
```

`iframe` side:

```
<p:commandButton value="Close" onsuccess="parent.dlg.hide();" ajax="true" process="@none" />
```

Comment: Reload is very expensive and I lose some data with that. But something similar can help

Comment: Addition to answer is that I had to add in onsuccess something like this: parent.dlg.showURL({src:''}); That was because if I entered some value in that form and then I hide it, if I want to open that iframe again, first I see is that values from before. That lasts second or two and then everything is normal